# String manipulation in Kotlin

Tags: string, kotlin

I have an application version string. The structure of the versioning is `x.x.x.x` I am using `Kotlin` to parse this value and I am trying to only pull the `major.minor` out of the version string, or `x.x`. I am struggling to find any String methods that can accomplish this.

`Code`:

```
fun main() {
    val appVersion = "15.2.855.15"
    val majorMinorVersion = appVersion.substring(0,4)
    println(majorMinorVersion)
}
```

`Output`:

```
15.2
```

I have tried using `Substring`, and that works most of the time if the major version is double digits. But, if it is single digits, then the output is `6.2.`. This can also go south if the minor version is double digits etc. I need a method where it will always print `major.minor`, no matter if major/minor are double or single digits.

Comment: `appVersion.substring(0,appVersion.indexOf(".",appVersion.indexOf(".")+1))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a clear way of doing this would be to split the string in its parts, and build the `major.minor` afterwards:

```kotlin
val appVersion = "15.2.855.15"
val (major, minor) = appVersion.split(".")
val majorMinorVersion = "$major.$minor"
```

Note: `split()` actually gives a list of 4 elements (the 4 parts of the version), but the destructuring declaration only takes the 2 first elements because 2 variables are in the parentheses.

Another approach as mentioned in the comments is to use `indexOf` to find the position of the dot:

```kotlin
val secondDotIndex = appVersion.indexOf(".", appVersion.indexOf(".") + 1)
val majorMinorVersion = appVersion.take(secondDotIndex)
```

You could also use a `Regex`, but that would be overkill IMO:

```kotlin
val appVersion = "15.2.855.15"
val versionRegex = Regex("""(\d+\.\d+)\.\d+\.\d+""")
val versionMatch = versionRegex.matchEntire(appVersion) ?: error("unexpected version format $appVersion")
val majorMinorVersion = versionMatch.groupValues[1]
```

Or a bit simpler but less reliable:

```kotlin
val appVersion = "15.2.855.15"
val majorMinorRegex = Regex("""\d+\.\d+""")
val majorMinorVersion = majorMinorRegex.find(appVersion)?.value ?: error("unexpected version format $appVersion")
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do it in functional style:

```kotlin
"15.2.855.15"
    .splitToSequence(".")
    .take(2)
    .joinToString(".")
```

Or we can look for the second `.` and then take a substring:

```kotlin
var counter = 2
"15.2.855.15".takeWhile { if (it == '.') counter--; counter > 0 }
```

This is harder to read, but probably has better performance as it avoids creating temporary data structures.